# html2pdf not working with the img tag.Download don't starts but When i remove the img tag it works

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

I have the following code. I am using an image in the html . When I run html2pdf script . Download don't starts but when i remove the image tag download starts. I want it with image . Any suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cstm">
    <h2>Hellow world</h2>
    <img src="img/user.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>


 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-GsLlZN/3F2ErC5ifS5QtgpiJtWd43JWSuIgh7mbzZ8zBps+dvLusV+eNQATqgA/HdeKFVgA5v3S/cIrLF7QnIg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


var element=document.getElementById("cstm");
html2pdf(element);
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a js error in your console?